# How to merge multiple arrays in pairs

Tags: python, arrays

I have a problem with "pairing" arrays into one (by index). Here is an example:

INPUT:

```
inputArray = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5, 7, 8], [9, 6, 1]]
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
outputArray = 
[[0,2,9],
[1,3,6],
[2,5,1],
[3,7,chooseRandom()],
[4,8,chooseRandom()]]
```

**Questions:**

1. <strike>How to avoid "out of range" "index error" problem</strike>
2. How to write chooseRandom() to choose N neighbour

**Answers:**

1. [SOLVED] Solutions provided by @jonrsharpe & @Christian & @Decency works as
   expected

**Clarification:**

By N neighbour I mean:
[image]

I'm using python but feel free to share your thoughts in any language.

Comment: 1. Do you mean `IndexError`? 2. Choose "N neighbour" from *what*? Please provide your code and a clearer description of what you're trying to achieve and where your code falls short. It seems likely that [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) will help.

Comment: What do you mean by choose N neighbour?

Comment: @jonsharpe - 1. I mean "out of range" error (in my example the last array have less values then first and second one. 2. Choose N neighbour from any array with more values. I think itertools could be an answer - i will take a look at it.

Comment: @user3688059 it would help to clarify if you would edit your question to provide expected outputs, defining what "N neighbour" means - clearly it is not currently unambiguous.

Comment: @user3688059: "out of range error" isn't a thing, although it's clear what you mean here.  If the error message says `IndexError: list index out of range`, then say that.  Better yet, show the code generating the error and the full traceback.

Comment: @user3688059 that still isn't clear.

Comment: @jonrsharpe by "next array" I mean nearest array to avoid pairs like array[0][1] with array[5][1]. To avoid random choices & if arrays have different length we need to find nearest neighbour in next/nearest array. In example above nearest neighbour for array1[4] is array2[2] (and this is N=1) for array1[4] is array2[3] (and in this case N=2) N == something like distance

Comment: @user3688059 nope, not getting it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following will do what you want:

```
from itertools import izip_longest # 'zip_longest' in Python 3.x
from random import choice

# Step 1
outputArray = list(map(list, izip_longest(*inputArray)))
# Step 2
for index, arr in enumerate(outputArray):
    if any(item is None for item in arr):
        valid = [item for item in arr if item is not None]
        outputArray[index] = [choice(valid) if item is None else item 
                              for item in arr]
```

This has two steps:

1. Combine all sub-lists of `inputArray` to the length of the longest sub-array, filling with `None`: `[[0, 2, 9], [1, 3, 6], [2, 5, 1], [3, 7, None], [4, 8, None]]`; and
2. Work through the `outputArray`, finding any sub-lists that contain `None` and replacing the `None` with a random choice from the other items in the sub-list that aren't `None`.

Example output:

```
[[0, 2, 9], [1, 3, 6], [2, 5, 1], [3, 7, 3], [4, 8, 8]]
```

Comment: Ah, I was having trouble finding a way to random.choice() without getting None elements. Creating valid solves that cleanly. In my solution (or yours), do you see a way to define the fillvalue parameter to zip and avoid the need to pass over the data a second time?

Comment: @Decency there is a pure Python equivalent in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) - you could roll your own that takes some kind of `fillfunc` and applies it in the `while iterators:` loop.

Comment: `izip_longest` is pretty fit for this problem. One question: why we need the outer `list` in `list(map(list, izip_longest(*inputArray)))`?

Comment: @WKPlus in [Python 3.x `map`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator, not a list. It is therefore not necessary (and actually *copies* the list that `map` builds) in 2.x, but I generally try to write code that works in both versions as far as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach to the problem, in Python 3.4. I don't really know what you mean by "choose N neighbour" but it should be pretty easy to write that however you'd like in the context below.

```
inputArray = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5, 7, 8], [9, 6, 1]]

import itertools

zipped = itertools.zip_longest(*inputArray, fillvalue=None)
outputArray = [list(item) for item in zipped]
# [[0, 2, 9], [1, 3, 6], [2, 5, 1], [3, 7, None], [4, 8, None]]

# Now replace the sentinel None in our sublists
for sublist in outputArray:
    for i, element in enumerate(sublist):
        if element is None:
            sublist[i] = chooseRandom()

print(outputArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most pythonic way, but you could try using this code snipped, read the comments in the code below:

```
import itertools, random

inputArray = [ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5, 7, 8], [9, 6, 1] ]
outputArray = []

max_length = max(len(e) for e in inputArray) # maximum length of the sublists in <inputArray>
i = 0 # to keep the index of sublists of <outputArray>

for j in range(max_length):
    outputArray.append([]) # add new sublist
    for e in inputArray: # iterate through each element of <inputArray>
        try:
            outputArray[i].append(e[j]) # try to append the number, if an exception is raised
                                        # then the code in the <except> clause will be executed
        except IndexError as e:
            outputArray[i].append(random.randint(0, 10)) # add the random number
    i += 1 # increase the sublists index on each iteration

print outputArray
# [[0, 2, 9], [1, 3, 6], [2, 5, 1], [3, 7, 3], [4, 8, 7]]
```

**Note:**

You may want to change the part

```
random.randint(0, 10)
```

to get the *"N neighbour"*.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know whether you like this code:

```
import random

array = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5, 7, 8], [9, 6, 1]]

max_len = max([len(l) for l in array])
dictionary = {}

for l in array:
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        if dictionary.has_key(i):
            dictionary[i].append(l[i])
        else:
            dictionary[i] = [l[i]]
    for i in range(len(l),max_len):
        if dictionary.has_key(i):
            dictionary[i].append(random.choice(l))
        else:
            dictionary[i] = [random.choice(l)]

print dictionary.values()
```